# Add function label's name as a class to HTML?

Tags: jquery

Im using a function label to pass on a state which is used as a condition for other functions.

This is working:

```
size: function() {
  if ($(window).width() > 1200) {
    this.label = "large";
  }
  else {
    this.label = "small";
  }
},
layout: function() {
  if (this.label == "large") {
    $('body').removeClass('size-small').addClass('size-large');
  }
  else if (this.label == "small") {
    $('body').removeClass('size-large').addClass('size-small');
  }
},
```

I would like to use the actual label text as part of the class name. Can I use something like this? The code isnt working but is it just a syntax issue?

```
size: function() {
  if ($(window).width() > 1200) {
    this.label = "large";
  }
  else {
    this.label = "small";
  }
},
layout: function() {
  if (this.label == "large") {
    $('body').removeClass('size-small').addClass('size-' this.label);
  }
  else if (this.label == "small") {
    $('body').removeClass('size-large').addClass('size-' this.label);
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a syntax issue. Change

```
addClass('size-' this.label);
```

to

```
addClass('size-' + this.label);
```